# Invalid column name - automapper

Tags: entity-framework, automapper, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I have a table with mulitple properties in it. I have an Id(PK) and a requestId(int, FK). We are improving the database structures of our tables. Since the RequestId(int, FK) is unique aswell we want to remove the Id(PK) and replace it with the RequestId(int, FK).

I've added a migration to achieve this.

```
DropForeignKey("dbo.Table1", "FK_Table1_Request");

DropIndex("dbo.Table1", new[] { "RequestId" });

DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Table1", "PK_Table1");

DropColumn("dbo.Table1", "Id");

RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Table1", name: "RequestId", newName: "Id");

AlterColumn("dbo.Table1", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false));

AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Table1", "Id");

CreateIndex("dbo.Table1", "Id");

AddForeignKey("dbo.Table1", "Id", "dbo.Table2", "Id");
```

So I've dropped the foreign keys, primary keys and indexes and added new ones for the RequestId.

When I run the update-database command it doesn't give any errors and the database has been updated. The colums are dropped and renamed correctly.

Now I want to retrieve some data from the database via an API Call. I'm using Automapper to map the properties from my DAL project and the API project. When I try to get the data via Postman I am getting this error:

> "exceptionMessage": "Error mapping types.\r\n\r\nMapping
>   types:\r\nPropertyRequest ->
>   PropertyRequestReadModel\r\nINIv2.Core.PropertyRequest ->
>   INIv2.WebApi.Models.Property.Request.PropertyRequestReadModel\r\n\r\nType
>   Map configuration:\r\nPropertyRequest ->
>   PropertyRequestReadModel\r\nINIv2.Core.PropertyRequest ->
>   INIv2.WebApi.Models.Property.Request.PropertyRequestReadModel\r\n\r\nProperty:\r\nExtensionOfCoverage",
>
> "exceptionMessage": "Invalid column name 'Request_Id'.",

The weird thing is that I never had a property Request_Id on my models and it is not a column in the database after the migration either.

Does anyone know why it is giving this error when the property doesn't exist?

EDIT 1

Readmodel:

```
public Table1ReadModel()
  {
    Perils = new HashSet<Table3ReadModel>();
  }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    public bool IsUsed { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Table3ReadModel> Perils { get; set; }



public class Table2: Table
    {
        public Table MaterialDamage { get; set; }
        public Table BusinessInterruption { get; set; }
        public Table ExtensionOfCoverage { get; set; }
    }
```

DAL model

```
public Table1(Table2 table2)
        {
            if (table2== null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tabe2));

            Table2 = table2;
            Perils = new HashSet<Table3>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        //public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        //public int RequestId { get; set; }
        public string Remarks { get; set; }
        public bool IsUsed { get; set; }

        #region IAuditable properties
        public DateTime CreDat { get; set; }
        public string CreUsr { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdDat { get; set; }
        public string UpdUsr { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Navigation properties
        public virtual Table3 Table3{ get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Table2> Perils { get; set; }


public Table2(RequestGroup requestGroup, RequestStatus requestStatus, string countryId) : base()
 {
       this.Table = new Table(this);
       this.Table = new Table(this);
       this.Table= new Table(this);
  }
        public virtual Table Table { get; set; }

        public virtual Table Table { get; set; }

        public virtual Table Table { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks, Brent

Comment: This sounds like a EF model mapping (configuration) issue rather than AutoMapper. From what you wrote it looks like you created migration manually while you should have modified your model and let EF generate the migration. Can you post the entity model (`Table1`, `Table2`) and fluent configuration if any?

Comment: The migrations were generated automatically at first but they were incorrect. So I changed them manually. In the original post I created an Edit part at the end. Those are my models

Comment: xxxxx_Id columns are created when you haven't properly configured your FK - zero to do with automapper as Ivan stated. Take you Table2 code for example. You have 3 references to table so EF needs 3 FK. You have some fluent code for that?